# Where Ruby get date, time from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in ruby, I have an object containing today's date, time from DB and only want time truncating the date. I can get,

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%H:%M")
```

I'm curious about where Ruby get date and time from? From internet, device or browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-new

Unless given a time during initialization of a Time instance, Ruby uses the type from the system it is running on.

If you want the current time on a user's device in a Rails project, you'll need to capture it with Javascript and pass it back to your Rails application.

Comment: It's helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While Ruby gets the time from the server it is running on, the server itself can either be counting from the last time it got set, just like a regular clock (and just like a regular clock, it can start going fast or lagging behind, or even get reset if its battery gets drained), or it could be getting synchronised with the several super-precise reference clocks around the world using NTP (Network Time Protocol), if it is set up on the server.